# An efficient way to write a list into a file write function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a list of column headers to a text file. I have this list also in as a variable but when I am writing the headers, I have to list it like this and using `\` to push items to the next line to make things neater screwed up the spacing in the text file. Is there any elegant way to unpack it from a list and do the same thing? I tried list comprehension but takes each item to the next line and that's not what I want. I want to create the names of the columns in a single line and go to the next line to append the values

```
f.write(
        "id, timestamp, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z, velocity_x, velocity_y, velocity_z, accl_x,accl_y, accl_z, ang_vel_x, ang_vel_y, ang_vel_z, orient, lat, lon, alt, coliision_intensity\n"
    )
```

Comment: ", ".join(list_of_Strings)

Comment: FYI adding `newline=""` as an argument to `open()` will stop a newline being written at the end of each write call, is an option here although I think the above from @Rob is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is an easy option:

```py
my_list = ["frame_id", "time_stamp", "pos_x"] # ... omitting elements

# Equivalent to f.write("frame_id, time_stamp, pos_x\n")
f.write(", ".join(my_list)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your question right, but how about a for loop which just appends each Header to the file without creating a New line? Otherwise, you could use a join method.

```
f.write(", ".join(list))
```